# How to access StyleData.value outside a component associated to an itemdelegate property?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml

I have a QML TreeView that contains a CustomQml assigned to the itemdelegate property, into the CustomQml I have access to all style.data properties and the attributes that were defined at C++ class and exposed by Q_PROPERTY but I would like to access these attributes outside the component.

```
TreeView 
{
   id: tree
   anchors.fill: parent
   model: theModel
   property var selectedRowIndex;
   itemDelegate:  CustomNode{ id: node }

   selection: sel

   TableViewColumn {
       role: "title"
       title: "Scenegraph"
   }

   style: TreeViewStyle {
       branchDelegate: Rectangle {
           width: 16; height: 16
           color: styleData.isExpanded ? "green" : "red"
       }

       rowDelegate: Rectangle {
             width: 18; height: 18
       }

       highlightedTextColor: "black"
       alternateBackgroundColor: "grey"
    }

   MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: tree.selection.setCurrentIndex(theModel.index,sel.ClearAndSelect)

        onClicked: {
           var index = parent.indexAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
           if (index.valid) {
               menu.popup()
               tree.selection.setCurrentIndex(index,sel.ClearAndSelect)
               // I want to access styleData.value.myproperty here, but this property is always "undefined"
               myFuction(styleData.value.myproperty) 
           }
        }
   }
}
```

What is the right way to access these properties and what I should do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to add a property to your delegate: `property QtObject style: styleData` (I guess QtObject should work). So if you have access to your delegate instance, you will have access to this property.

Comment: If I understood right I should create a property into the CustomNode like this: CustomNode { id: node; property QtObject style: styleData } and then I could access this property. I did this test but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I received object undefined!

Comment: I think you should have the `MouseArea` inside an `itemDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I already did it, but I thought that it wasn't the best way because I will need to put everything that must access `StyleData` inside the `itemDelegate`, it doesn't look right!

Comment: As an alternative, you can try to use derM's solution, but access the `styleData` using `tree.childAt(mouse.x, mouse.y).style` instead of `node.style`.

Comment: Thank you all, I couldn't figure out other solution until now, except put everything into my CustomNode and use styleData from there. I hope that it won't be as ugly as I think, but it is working fine for now.